# $ABCD$ is a trapezium where $AB$ $||$ $CD$. Suppose $[\Delta BOC] = \frac{25}{9}$, and let $AB = b$, $CD = a$ where $a < b$.

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, area, polygons

> $ABCD$ is a trapezium where $AB$ $||$ $CD$. Suppose $[\Delta BOC] = \frac{25}{9}$, and let $AB = b$, $CD = a$ where $a < b$. Find the value of $\frac{b}{a}$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

I really have no idea on how to start this. I might proceed by giving variables to the side lengths and use similarity and area, but I am sure this will be length and quite complicated. There is as little information as possible, and I got no idea how to solve it.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: There is definitely insufficient information. It is easy to "bend" this trapezium very, very close to a rectangle/square. You can also scale any trapezium to fit the area requirement.

Comment: I second player3236's comment.  Intuitively, the "area = (25/9)" fact is an **absolute** fact, while the problem is to prove a **proportional** fact.  My intuition is that the absolute fact is insufficient to prove the proportional fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer**

As observed in the comments the trapezoid is not unique. See the picture below

---

$$
...
$$
[image]